# Android, WebView, loadUrl

Tags: android, webview

I have a strange problem. My app is working perfectly on most of devices but on some of them not (e.g. Galaxy S5 mini).

I tested this on https://app.testobject.com/ and on Galaxy S5 mini works ok for even instalations, odd instalations don't load content to webView (I guess, I can see only blank page, I cannot reproduce it on my phones).

My code from Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());

        appConfig = new AppConfig(this);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);

        appWebView = new AppWebView(webView, progressBar, this, appConfig);

        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        appWebView.loadUrlAndRequestFocus(appConfig.getAppStartUrl());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Fabric.getLogger().e("WebView loading error", e.getMessage(), e);
        Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And my AppWebView:

```
public AppWebView(WebView webView, ProgressBar progressBar, Activity parentActivity, AppConfig appConfig) {
    this.webView = webView;
    this.progressBar = progressBar;
    this.parentActivity = parentActivity;
    this.appConfig = appConfig;

    configureWebView();
    setAppIdStringAndInstanceIdCookie();
}
....
public void loadUrlAndRequestFocus(String url) {
    // ładujemy stronę główną słownika
    webView.loadUrl(url);

    // ustawiamy fokus na kontrolce webview
    webView.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you getting any error in logcat?

Comment: Some leads you might want to follow: is the number of installations of consequence even if you don't run the app at all (that would be very very strange...)? Quick test: what does happen if you remove the app, then install the app twice, but run it only the second time (it should behave like an even installation)? What does happen if you go into the app info and clear the app data completely on a even installation? EDIT: for extra credits, what does happen on subsequent installations? You didn't specify that in the question.

Comment: Problem is that I cannot reproduce on my phone or virtual device. This problem is reported by users and is reproducing on this page -  https://app.testobject.com/ (but only odd instalations)

Unfortunatelly logs in this page are so big, anyway I can see there interesting log :/ I can't find these log "Fabric.getLogger().e("WebView loading error", e.getMessage(), e);"

Comment: I don't know the testobject service: can you download an image of your installation when the bug happens? That would be very useful...

Comment: Anyway, if it only happens on a single device and just one, I would advise you to do some testing, and when you are out of ideas, ask for clarifications to the service provider (reporting what you tried to debug the issue on your end): maybe you have spot an issue with their testing service (they may even be glad that you helped them).

Comment: Problem is that sometimes content is loaded, sometimes not on screen (blank page from application, the same what before content is loaded correctly) on some devices. Problem on more than one device:

Comment: then I would advise you to bisect your issue until you find the culprit, it's a hard problem on your end, but an even harder one on our (as we miss both the testing means and the code): unless some savior appears with a ready solution you might be out of luck here (just my opinion).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was new wildcard's certificate and old webview from google. Updating webview/chrome (old android's versions use separated webviews, newer chrome's webviews) helped.